How to delete critical errors in event viewer from powershell?
I want to create a script to delete critical error found in both application and system logs in event viewer. I want this to be done every week so I will be using task scheduler to accomplish this. However, I am having trouble creating the script to delete critical errors in event viewer. For starters I am not sure which level option should I include as the Windows documentation for it does not specify how many levels are available, making this very vague.
I tired to run the following script but Powershell deletes everything all events in the application log (information, warning, and error): wevtutil qe Application /q:"*[System[(Level=2)]]" /f:txt | wevtutil cl Application

This seems somewhat like tampering with evidence.

Unfortunately my original aswer does not hold up to its promises and therefore i retracted it. wevtutil does not provide an option to delete specific event log entries based on filters like event level (Level=1). The wevtutil cl command clears the entire log and wevtutil qe Application /q:"*[System[(Level=1)]]" /f:Text only queries them. U could try exporting, filtering and reimporting them but that does not strike me to be an adequate approach.

What are you hoping to accomplish by selectively purging events like this?
